# Android Soundpool Issue

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

Recently I've been working on an android game, but have hit a problem when adding music and other sounds. I read that Mediaplayers are optimal for background music, which works well, and I read that Soundpool is optimal for short music clips like sound effects. However, I can't get the Soundpool to work, it appears that the Soundpool isn't even loading.

I did more research and found a lot of nightmare stories about Soundpool's lack of support, so should I just use a mediaplayer for all audio? Is this efficient?

```
//My Code
soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int mySoundId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });

    if(loaded==true){
     soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
     soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);}
    else{
         System.exit(0);
     }
            //Forces the program to exit everytime
```

Answer (score 1):

`SoundPool#load` method is asynchronous, you should play sound after `onLoadComplete` had been invoked

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int mySoundId, int status) {        
        soundPool.play(mySoundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
});

soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int mySoundId, int status) {
        loaded = true;
        soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
        soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
});
```

because your loaded variable will be always false, you should do the things within the onLoadComplete.